# How to Display one by one, the values or Elements of an array on next button- in Codeigniter(php)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I m developing an online examination system. I am getting 50 questions randomly from the database. I want to display only one at a time out of all the questions on the next button. I am confused after getting the whole array, how to display a single question on next button click.

Code in model `Showmodel` (database):

```
     <?php
     class Showmodel extends CI_Model{  
    function show_questions(){
                            $this->db->select('*');
                            $this->db->from('questions');
                           return $this->db->get()->result_array();
                          }  }?>
```

Code in controller:

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 */
class Candidate extends MY_Controller
{
    
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Showmodel','show',TRUE);
        //$this->load->model('admin/showmodel','show',TRUE); 
    }
    function index(){

        $data['qtn']=$this->show->show_questions();
        $this->load->view('test',$data);
      }

     }?>
```

Code in view (named tes.php)

```
    <?php
$start=0;
$id=$qtn[$start];
$nid=$id['question_id'];
$question=$id['question'];
echo $question;// displaying the quetsion
echo $nid; //displaying Id
?>
```

**Note:** now the problem is I am getting the question Id by calling by calling array index(0). but I want to increment it by `$start++` which is not working.

In short, the array $qtn is available in the view, then how to display the elements one by one / incrementally by next button click.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIPyr.png)

An image is added for clear understanding what actually I want.

Comment: You can call ajax and store data into JS variable as array and on next click increment start++ which is a index of your array.

Comment: `$this->db->orderby('rand');` for random result.

Comment: Ali Qorbani-Bor. I Need the solution to display the elements of the array one by one by next button click.